# Ubuntu hangs while logging off

Tags: 15.10

This is a Ubuntu 15.10 installation running gnome.

If I logoff, it lands me at the command line, and I get the message:
"**A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth boot screen to quit (42s/No limit)**".

The only option at that point is to switch to another tty, login as root and reboot. 
Edit: It appears I can also switch to another tty and run 'startx' to get back X. However the previous tty appears hung up forever.

I have not modified any system settings recently, and have not meddled with init. Tell me what logs can help me get to the bottom of this.

The screen shows:
[image]

The process list at this point shows:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 07:59 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:0]
root         7     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root         8     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/0]
root        10     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/0]
root        11     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root        12     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root        13     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
root        14     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root        15     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        16     2  1 07:59 ?        00:00:08 [kworker/1:0]
root        17     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        18     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/1]
root        19     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/1]
root        20     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root        21     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        22     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        23     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [perf]
root        24     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        25     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root        26     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        27     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
root        28     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
root        29     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
root        30     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        31     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root        32     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
root        33     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [md]
root        34     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        36     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        37     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
root        39     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        40     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [vmstat]
root        41     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        42     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        53     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root        54     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root        58     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root        59     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2]
root        78     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]
root        79     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
root       126     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kpsmoused]
root       129     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       130     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       131     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       132     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       133     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       134     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       135     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       136     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_3]
root       137     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       138     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_4]
root       139     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       140     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_5]
root       141     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:2]
root       142     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:3]
root       143     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:4]
root       144     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:5]
root       145     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:6]
root       146     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:7]
root       149     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:8]
root       154     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_6]
root       155     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_6]
root       156     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [usb-storage]
root       176     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root       179     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       185     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root       201     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-worker]
root       202     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u17:0]
root       203     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-worker-hi]
root       204     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-delalloc]
root       205     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
root       206     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-cache]
root       207     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-submit]
root       208     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-fixup]
root       209     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio]
root       210     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root       211     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root       212     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
root       213     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-rep]
root       214     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-rmw]
root       215     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root       216     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-freespace]
root       217     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
root       218     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-readahead]
root       219     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
root       220     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-extent-re]
root       221     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
root       222     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-transacti]
root       255     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root       276     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       287     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       370     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [cfg80211]
root       383     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [irq/27-mei_me]
root       401     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [irq/28-iwlwifi]
root       413     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [iwlwifi]
root       437     2  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
systemd+   469     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root       592     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
avahi      594     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [lifebook.local]
whoopsie   600     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/whoopsie -f
clamav     603     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true
root       606     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root       607     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       608     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
root       612     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root       613     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable
root       614     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
syslog     615     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
message+   616     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
avahi      631   594  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root       650     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
root       674     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
root       679     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root       706     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       759   614  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-wlp1s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-fe21adb4-91c0-4e81-8353-6168b8be4adf-wlp1s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp1s0.conf wlp1s0
nobody     768   614  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
root       919     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/gdm
kernoops   933     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/kerneloops
root       992     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root      1076     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/nmbd -D
minidlna  1085     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/minidlnad -f /etc/minidlna.conf -P /run/minidlna/minidlna.pid
root      1089     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
root      1090  1089  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
rtkit     1145     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
root      1152     1  0 07:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
colord    1178     1  0 08:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/colord/colord
root      1249     1  0 08:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd --no-debug
root      1291     1  0 08:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
root      1373     1  0 08:00 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login --     
root      1503     1  0 08:00 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/mazy/Ultra 2TB -o rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,uhelper=udisks2
uuidd     1534     1  0 08:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/uuidd --socket-activation
root      2303     2  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u17:1]
root      2452     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:2]
root      2453     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:3]
root      2454     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:4]
root      2455     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:5]
root      2456     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:6]
root      2458     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root      2459     2  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:3]
mazy      2528     1  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
mazy      2529  2528  0 08:08 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)         
mazy      2533  1373  0 08:08 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
mazy      2546  2533  0 08:08 tty1     00:00:00 ps -ef
```

It does not show any process associated with tty7 (the hung one)

If I run agetty from another tty, I can get tty7 to hand me the login shell:

`agetty -s 38400 -t 600 tty7 linux`

But I am not close to discovering why I cant logout.

Comment: When you switch to a tty, investigate `ps -ef | less`, etc. Have you changed anything in `/etc/init`?

Comment: @waltinator Added the process list, and the screen at this point